Deployment Error on Solana Mainnet: Max Retries Exceeded
I've been successfully deploying my Anchor project on Solana's development and testnet environments. However, when attempting deployment on the mainnet, I consistently encounter the following error: "Max retries exceeded." Below is the content of my TOML file:
[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false

[programs.devnet]
solana_contract = "EEETpgqxVBBW7MgmhXU1iH763C2xBpBV7VmnLxjFx2Ga"

[registry]
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

[provider]
cluster = "mainnet"
wallet = "PATH TO id.json File"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

Additionally, I am using Solana CLI version 1.18.12, Anchor version 0.29.0, and Cargo version 1.76.0.
I've tried the following command to deploy, even paying extra SOL:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/solana_contract.so --with-compute-unit-price 1900000
Despite these efforts, the deployment fails with the mentioned error. I've double-checked my configuration, and everything seems correct. Even I tried the other RPC's and i am sure connection to the main net is correct as some times it will go till %99. Could someone please advise on what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it to successfully deploy on the Solana mainnet?
Thank you in advance for any assistance!

I met the same issue for a few days. Any once can help? Thanks.

No, I followed solutions given on link not worked for me.
